# How to backup a Windows driver using Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, backup, drivers

Can someone please help me and tell me how I can backup a Windows driver programmatically using Delphi?

Any code samples, links to articles are highly appreciated

Thanks for your time

Comment: This question makes no sense. What is problematically? And what does backing up a driver mean? I suggest you edit your question to explain more, including what you have tried so far, e.g. web search results etc.

Comment: Hold your horses sir, this was just a typo mistake so no need for all the locomotion...I meant 'programmatically' and I am writing 'programmatically' in order to avoid getting answers on how to do this manually from Windows

What does backing up a driver mean? I am not sure which part of the question you didn't understand....was it the backup part or the driver part?! Please elaborate so that I can explain in more simplified words

I've tried web search results and couldn't find any answer on how to backup any Windows driver using Delphi

Comment: If there is a programmatic way of backing up a driver in Windows, this will depend on the Windows API only, and so the solution will look the same in every programming language: Delphi, C, C++, VB, ... Hence, this question has really nothing to do with Delphi in particular.

Comment: I would also like to know what you mean by backing up a driver... The whole thing, not the backup part or the driver part. I know what a backup is and what a driver is, but you'll have to be more specific. How would you go about backing up a driver manually?

Comment: wouldn't you just download the driver installation from the vendor and back that up? This questions looks like leading to a solution in search of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source of the DevCon utility which is included in the [Windows Driver Kit (WinDDK) for Windows 2008 R2/Windows 7 (7.1.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=36a2630f-5d56-43b5-b996-7633f2ec14ff).

DevCon Sample

DEVCON

DevCon is a command-line tool that displays detailed information about devices, and lets you search for and manipulate devices from the command line. DevCon enables, disables, installs, configures, and removes devices on the local computer and displays detailed information about devices on local and remote computers. DevCon is included in the Windows DDK.

This should point you to which API's you need.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a Windows driver (and having Windows backup the previous one) requires to follow some rules you can find for example [here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/install/default.mspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549731%28VS.85%29.aspx) (not difficult to find...). You can also create a restore point, if needed. Anyway you should explain if you'd like to "backup" a driver because you're installing a new one (and let Windows take care of it), or you just need to "backup" drivers even if the system is unmodified, to a device of your choice.